# Left and right aligned text in html menu items

Tags: html, css, nav

What I need are menu items where you have left aligned item text and right aligned keyboard shortcuts in the `same` menu item, like in classical menus of any computer programm.

[image: Computer program styled menu]

html example :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 1 ...  &#8963&#8997 B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 3 </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can I place in the `<li>` tag two `<a>` tags one for left and one for right aligned text like this ?

```
<li> <a href="#"> menu item 1 ...</a>  <a>&#8963&#8997 B</a>  </li>
```

How to achieve this with CSS ?

Comment: An image of what this is **supposed** to look like would be useful here as it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here i tried to solve your example code here and i do following it's working

> **Note:** if your structure would be same as you have given then you may
>   go for it or you can refer this

```css
.submenu{
    display:block;
    width:160px;
}
ul.submenu li{
    background-color:green;
    width:inherit;
}
ul.submenu li a:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:grey;    
}
ul.submenu li a:nth-child(even){
    clear: right;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"> menu item 1 ...</a>  <a>&#8963&#8997 B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 2 </a>  <a>&#8963&#8997 C</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 3 </a>  <a>&#8963&#8997 D</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**[My DEmo](https://jsfiddle.net/4g39shev/)**

Comment: @Ben please check out my answer

Comment: I accepted Himesh Aadeshara anwer as it could help me best to continue with my menus. Now I know how to allign text left and right in one item, thanks for this.  Still I have some troubles to integrate that code into my menu structure. But that I will manage later.

Comment: @Ben honored to help you feel free to ask we are here to help you out by our efforts

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in only one particular tag. You should first define a fixed width for the parent tag and then algin them accordingly

See this here: https://jsfiddle.net/5a6nnvxo/

I.e. you could try to achieve your goal by using the

```
float: right;
```

command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS tag `float` to do this. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/no3q003y/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. Just put in the icon (be it image or text or whatever) in a `<span></span>`

> **NOTE** You don't have to use `span`, a `div` with an ID or Class works just as well

The width of the `li` is just there to give a fixed size.

```css
span {
  float: right;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 1 ...  <span>&#8963&#8997 B</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >menu item 3 </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```